# Shell scripts in windows

Tags: windows, vim, terminal, terminal-emulator

I've been using the terminal in Ubuntu and Debian for a while and use shell scripts, commands like find, grep etc.. and the vim editor.

What is the best way to use such commands/software under windows? ( with auto-completion, history in the terminal )? Is using cygwin the best option?

Comment: **Answer: Yes.** Have you tried it? Any special problems with Cygwin?

Comment: Try Cygwin with Console2, or Gow

Comment: @slhck No, I haven't tried it. The reason why I asked before using is because it would take a long time to install and check all available options (such as MinGW as some resources mentioned). Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Windows has:

- .bat files
- .vbs files
- Windows PowerShell

and you can install Cygwin. I'd recommend learning PowerShell as this is a 'native' Windows shell that provides very sophisticated set of commands.